# Why is Dot Net Avalonia hello-world application so huge (80 MB)?

Tags: .net, .net-core, avaloniaui, avalonia

Create a default Dot Net Avalonia MVVM application project in MSVS 2022.

Build ready-to-publish release version using command
`dotnet publish .\AvaloniaApplication1.csproj -r win-x64 -c Release -p:publishsinglefile=true --self-contained true -p:debugsymbols=false -p:debugtype=none -o HelloWorld`

We got a release of three files with overall size 84.6 MB.

I believe the size of hello-world GUI project should not exceed 1 MB. Is it possible? Or, at least, how to reduce the size as much as possible?

Comment: _"I believe the size of hello-world GUI project should not exceed 1 MB"_ - why do you believe so, especially taking in account that you bundling the whole runtime with the app (`--self-contained true`)? Also what .NET version are you using? You can try looking into assembly trimming to reduce the app size.

Comment: `-self-contained true`. You're bundling the entire runtime. The command line doesn't contain any trimming parameters and I suspect neither does the `csproj` file

Comment: Check the docs at [Trim self-contained deployments and executables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trim-self-contained).

Answer (score 3):

At a guess, this is your issue:

> --sc|--self-contained [true|false]
>
> Publishes the .NET runtime with your application

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish

Maybe you need to do this, maybe not